# How does GAE deal with regex URL handlers?

Tags: google-app-engine, wsgi

If I have something like:

```
webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/foo/?', FooHandler),
    (r'/bar/(\d+)', BarPermHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Then the result is that both `/foo` and `/foo/` are handled by my `FooHandler` class, and `/bar/x` where `x` is a string of digits by `BarPermHandler`.

My first concern was that this might create *two identical* pages `/foo`, `/foo/` rather than having one of them redirect to the other, which Google's search results would surely dislike.

However I started to doubt myself after considering the `/bar/x` path - I don't think it's much of a stretch to assume that GAE doesn't create a page for every possible integer up to whatever the maximum URL length is!

---

So my question is, how are these handled? Which one 'exists'? In search results, are users linked to `/foo` or `/foo/` or potentially both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you mean by "creating a page". GAE doesn't create any pages at all, they are all handled dynamically.

The issue for the first URL, as you seem to have understood, is not just that there are two similar URLs, but that both URLs point to exactly the same content. By contrast, presumably BarPermHandler will show different content depending on which integer is passed, so there is no problem with SEO in that case.

Comment: Yes, I realise that was a shady sentence. I meant in terms of visibility to a crawler, I suppose.

If I search specifically enough to guarantee finding my `foo` page in results, would I see links to both `/foo` and `/foo/`?

If so, presumably a "normal search" would rank both those pages very poorly? Or are most crawlers "intelligent" enough to deal with it appropriately (ideally show result for only one)?

Comment: It's more about how you index it than anything else. Search engines only index what you tell them to, or what they can find via a crawler. If you can ensure that all your links only point to one version of the URL, then the crawler should only find that page, and you should be OK. But you might be better off only having one URL anyway, and doing the redirection manually - say in middleware, which is eg how Django does it.

Comment: Sorry to revisit this - but it just occurred to me that even if I consistently link with/without trailing `/` in internal links, I cant stop external sites breaking that scheme. Isn't that a problem?